# Consuming RESTful APIs using Java

Tags: java, api, rest

How would you consume a RESTful API using Java with probably just the standard packages? For ex: Twitter API. I know there are great Java libraries to access it, but how would you start from scratch?

Comment: you should probably have a look at @bhagyas answer. The most appropriate I feel

Answer (score 8):

Well, there are many ways you could access RESTful API using Java third party libraries, like using  [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)  or 
using [Sun Jersey API](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with).

You could also use the native java.net.HttpURLConnection to consume REST Services

Answer (score 5):

Don't think you should start from scratch, however Spring's RestTemplate is something you can simple use to consume RESTful Services.

http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/

Cheers.