# Bing local search listing information?

Tags: bing-maps, yahoo-api, google-local-search

I read the Bing documentation but can't find a way to query Bing for local listing information such as name, address, phone, website, claimed or not, number of reviews and some snippets, and images associated with the listing if any, etc. Is there any RESTFul search API for this purpose? Could you point me to the correct API?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to find this kind of information in Bing Maps for Enterprise platform.
Here some links that might be helpful:

- Bing Maps REST Spatial Data Service (Public Data sources): 
  NAVTEQEU: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478193.aspx
  NAVTEQNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478192.aspx
- Bing Maps REST Location API, if you're looking for geocoding and places:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx
- Bing Maps SOAP Search service (consider not using it, I recommend to use REST instead of this one)
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980849.aspx
- Bing Search 2.0 also includes location information, see on Azure Data Markeplace:
  http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

You should be able to find what is appropriate to your needs and also keep in mind the licensing associated to those platform and services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am using Java. can i use java to call the API ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course you can, all services described here are usable in any languages. Prefer JSON response (rather than XML), response would be smaller in most of the cases. Call a REST service using Java should be pretty simple, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177628/calling-restful-service-from-java

Comment: How do I search for Business listing data using Bing Search API? Couldn't find adequate documentation on that.

Comment: Here are the basic that you should be able to update using the new URI: http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html