# How to invoke a ASP.NET Web API from Java

Tags: web-services, apache, rest, asp.net-web-api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to implement a function using java code to invoke an ASP.NET Web API on remote server. Is there any library that I could use, like axis2 for Web Services?
I think the Apache HttpClient could help me to create a requrest, is there any other choice?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, Asp.net Web API is simply a Restful Service that can be call from many technologies (javascript, C#, java, php, ...) Unlike Soap formatting, it is much more easier to call this kind of service. Try with your browser !

You can find many librairies on google or in SO ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177628/calling-restful-service-from-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262202/consuming-restful-apis-using-java)).